# Newly Created toolbar icon is not Showing in the Toolbar

Tags: c#, plugins, icons, notepad++, toolbar

I want to add a new icon to the Notepad++ toolbar.
I've tried following code

```
internal static void SetToolBarIcon()
{
    toolbarIcons tbIcons = new toolbarIcons();
    tbIcons.hToolbarBmp = tbBmp.GetHbitmap();
    IntPtr pTbIcons = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(tbIcons));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(tbIcons, pTbIcons, false);
    Win32.SendMessage(PluginBase.nppData._nppHandle, NppMsg.NPPM_ADDTOOLBARICON, PluginBase._funcItems.Items[idMyDlg]._cmdID, pTbIcons);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pTbIcons);
}
```

Now my problem is that instead of an icon I only see a black square in the toolbar

Comment: I have the same problem with Notepad++ 6.9.1 on Windows Server 2008 R2 running in a VMWare.
Strange is that the icon shows fine on Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit that is not running in a VMWare with the same Npp version!
I have no idea if this is related to VMWare or not

Comment: any solution found for this issue ? i am facing the same issue now, its running fine on win10 but showing a square black box on win 7 enterprise

Answer (score 0):

Remember to save your icon in the `Resources.resx`